# wpf - Menu item highlighted only when over text

Tags: wpf, styles

Can someone please tell me why my menu item is "Highlighted" only when I hover over the menu text and not when I hover anywhere on the menu item? Here's my menu item style:

```
            <Style x:Key="CtxMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="31" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="20"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!-- ContentPresenter to show an Icon if needed -->
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>

                                <!-- Glyph is a checkmark if needed for a checkable menu -->
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanelpath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                                </Grid>

                                <!-- Content for the menu text etc -->
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            x:Name="HeaderHost"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                            ContentSource="Header"/>

                                <!-- The Popup is the body of the menu which expands down or across depending on the level of the item -->
                                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2,2,2,2">
                                        <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                            <!-- StackPanel holds children of the menu. This is set by IsItemsHost=True -->
                                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <!-- These triggers re-configure the four arrangements of MenuItem to show different levels of menu via Role -->
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <!-- If no Icon is present the we collapse the Icon Content -->
                            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="Icon"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <!-- Using the system colors for the Menu Highlight and IsEnabled-->
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF08A5E1"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE1E0E0"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: I would inspect your control with snoop to see if your grid isn't blocking the event of mouseover. I.E. it looks like you got the MenuItem, then the Grid with the Path and then the text. The text is catching the MouseOver but the Grid blocks it to the MenuItem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your MenuItem is only hit-testable for pixels it, or it's descendants, actually renders. You need to add a Transparent background to your outer border:

```
<Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent">
```